# Python index error: too many indices for array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to code a plot with this code:

```
for k in range(5):
   plt.scatter(np.arange(0,200),cprofit[:,k],label = marketshare)
a = pd.Series([np.mean(cprofit[:,k]), np.std(cprofit[:,k]), np.max(cprofit[:,k]), np.min(cprofit[:,k])], index=df.columns)
df = df.append(a,ignore_index=True)
```

The error:

```
a = pd.Series([np.mean(cprofit[:,k]), np.std(cprofit[:,k]), np.max(cpro fit[:,k]), np.min(cprofit[:,k])], index=df.columns)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional,  but 2 were indexed
```

for line

What could be wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like the problem line has multiple instances of `cprofit[:,k]`.  What's `cprofit.shape`?  That indexing implies 2d, right?  But the error says it's 1d.  Is that what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The two inputs of `plt.scatter()` should be of the same dimension, and size. You have `numpy.arange(0, 200)` creating a 1-dimensional array of size 200, and it's unclear what `cprofit[:,k]` is doing, but it seems to be slicing a large 2-D array, which may or may not produce a 1-D array of size 200.